# How to enter a LaTeX integral?

Tags: formatting, latex

How can I enter a LaTeX integral into *Mathematica*? For example, I evaluated the expression

```
ToExpression["\int 2*x\[DifferentialD]x ", TeXForm]
```

but *Mathematica* told me that this is wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at

```
TeXForm[Integrate[f[x], x]]
```

We see that integrals can be entered like:

```
ToExpression["\int f(x) \, dx", TeXForm]
(* \[Integral]f[x]\[DifferentialD]x *)
```

Comment: This can be done a little more directly with `TeXForm @ HoldForm @ Integrate[2 x, x]`, which gives `\int 2 x \, dx`